# Select value from hidden drop down menu with Python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, select, dropdown

I'm trying to make an automation script for tests. My issue is that I can't select a value from drop down menu. I've try a lot of things , but can't make it. My goal is the script to choose every time different value from the menu. When I click the hidden menu , it create a 'ul class' with about 100 'li classes' . There are no id, name or class. I don't know how to reach the element there and click it.
Things that I've tried...

`elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]')
all_li = elem.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
gg = random.choice(all_li)
gg = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul > li:nth-child(15)").click()`

[html code, this is what generate html when hit menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bma12.jpg)
This is my code:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div").click()`

Simple html:

```
<div class="MuiPaper-root MuiMenu-paper MuiPaper-elevation8 MuiPopover-paper MuiPaper-rounded" role="document" tabindex="-1" style="opacity: 1; transform: none; min-width: 491px; transition: opacity 381ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms, transform 254ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms; top: 80px; left: 16px; transform-origin: -1px 478.513px;">
<ul class="MuiList-root MuiMenu-list MuiList-padding" role="listbox" tabindex="-1" style="padding-right: 17px; width: calc(100% + 17px);">
<li class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-disabled="false" variant="outlined" data-value="testOne">Test One<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></li>
<li class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-disabled="false" variant="outlined" data-value="testTwo">Test Two<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></li>
```

Comment: can you add a sample html code here with the values you are looking to select?

Comment: I edit my post and post example. I'm looking for li classes.

Comment: wait for li element be visible, and click -> Use Explicit Waits
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: I'll try it a little later. Thanks